# Can't rebuild deployment with PersistentVolumeClaim

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I want to create a MongoDB deployment with a PersistentVolumeClaim.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Mi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-depl
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-mongo-pod-label
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-mongo-pod-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth-mongo-pod
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: auth-mongo-volume
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: auth-mongo-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: auth-mongo-pvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth-mongo-pod-label
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

[full code](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/microservices-quiz-app/tree/7bcfbcb3118eec3f1be6ba7409185cb32db82660)

First build after creating autopilot cluster:

```
Starting deploy...
 - Warning: Autopilot set default resource requests for Deployment default/auth-depl, as resource requests were not specified. See http://g.co/gke/autopilot-defaults
 - deployment.apps/auth-depl created
 - service/auth-srv created
 - persistentvolumeclaim/auth-mongo-pvc created
 - Warning: Autopilot set default resource requests for Deployment default/auth-mongo-depl, as resource requests were not specified. See http://g.co/gke/autopilot-defaults
 - deployment.apps/auth-mongo-depl created
 - service/auth-mongo-srv created
 - Warning: Autopilot set default resource requests for Deployment default/react-client-depl, as resource requests were not specified. See http://g.co/gke/autopilot-defaults
 - deployment.apps/react-client-depl created
 - service/react-client-srv created
 - ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress-service created
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/auth-depl: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu, 2 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/auth-depl-77fd8b57f5-vk8cf: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu, 2 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu, 2 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/auth-mongo-depl-7d967468f6-rkh79: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu, 2 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/react-client-depl: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu, 2 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/react-client-depl-68dcb844f6-b8fm9: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu, 2 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/auth-depl: Unschedulable: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu, 2 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/auth-depl-77fd8b57f5-vk8cf: Unschedulable: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu, 2 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/react-client-depl: Unschedulable: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu, 2 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/react-client-depl-68dcb844f6-b8fm9: Unschedulable: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient cpu, 2 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/react-client-depl is ready. [2/3 deployment(s) still pending]
 - deployment/auth-depl is ready. [1/3 deployment(s) still pending]
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl is ready.
Deployments stabilized in 2 minutes 31.285 seconds
```

[mongo pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXImJ.png)

If I click on "Rebuild" in Google Cloud Build, I get:

```
Starting deploy...
 - deployment.apps/auth-depl configured
 - service/auth-srv configured
 - persistentvolumeclaim/auth-mongo-pvc unchanged
 - deployment.apps/auth-mongo-depl configured
 - service/auth-mongo-srv configured
 - deployment.apps/react-client-depl configured
 - service/react-client-srv configured
 - ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress-service unchanged
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/auth-depl: 0/5 nodes are available: 5 Insufficient cpu, 5 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/5 nodes are available: 5 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/auth-depl-666fdb5c64-cqnf6: 0/5 nodes are available: 5 Insufficient cpu, 5 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/5 nodes are available: 5 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl: 0/5 nodes are available: 5 Insufficient cpu, 5 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/5 nodes are available: 5 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/auth-mongo-depl-958db4cd5-db5pr: 0/5 nodes are available: 5 Insufficient cpu, 5 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/5 nodes are available: 5 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/react-client-depl: 0/5 nodes are available: 5 Insufficient cpu, 5 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/5 nodes are available: 5 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
    - pod/react-client-depl-54998f6c5b-wswz7: 0/5 nodes are available: 5 Insufficient cpu, 5 Insufficient memory. preemption: 0/5 nodes are available: 5 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
 - deployment/auth-mongo-depl: Unschedulable: 0/1 nodes available: 1 node is not ready
    - pod/auth-mongo-depl-958db4cd5-db5pr: Unschedulable: 0/1 nodes available: 1 node is not ready
 - deployment/auth-depl is ready. [2/3 deployment(s) still pending]
 - deployment/react-client-depl is ready. [1/3 deployment(s) still pending]
1/3 deployment(s) failed
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/skaffold:v2.2.0" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

[second pod is stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLxFb.png)
[pod events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkar5.png)

I am not sure why it can't scale up "Node scale up in zones us-central1-f associated with this pod failed: GCE quota exceeded. Pod is at risk of not being scheduled."; how can I be exceeding a quota with such a simple deployment? Although it does say "Scheduled" after "FailedAttachVolume".

Should I change my `skaffold.yml` file to not even attempt to rebuild deployments of databases? I am not familiar with taint; should I be changing a setting so that the same node is used?

I did try ReadWriteMany in a previous cluster but it didn't work. [pod events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCtVW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a StatefulSet, since it is required anyway for horizontal scaling.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Mi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-set
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-mongo-pod-label
  serviceName: auth-mongo-srv
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-mongo-pod-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth-mongo-pod
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: auth-mongo-volume
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: auth-mongo-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: auth-mongo-pvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-mongo-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth-mongo-pod-label
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

I think that now each pod has its own PVC, so there are no issues when trying to replace an old pod with a new one (with deployments, both pods use the same pvc).